# AWS S3 redirect to secured external url without Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, redirect, amazon-s3

I have a custom domain and I managed to redirect the naked(apex) domain to www subdomain using S3 static website hosting redirect over http. (Without using Cloudfront) (http:// ...)

[AWS S3 redirect window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtDoc.png)

Now that I have setup SSL certificate at my server, my redirect url is secured. And I wish to redirect all the traffic from apex domain to this secured url now. (https:// ...)

On first thought, I changed the protocol in the S3 static website redirect config to https, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Documents and other links suggest that I need to make use of Amazon Cloud Front and setup certificate and then the redirection would happen (haven't tried yet).

My question is, since I have setup the certificate at my server, the url I am redirecting to is already secured, I do not wish to do the same in Cloud front. Is there a way I can redirect all traffic from to a secured url without setting up cloud front?

Comment: You only need CloudFront if you need HTTPS on the *first* domain -- the one on the bucket.  *"On first thought, I changed the protocol in the S3 static website redirect config to https, but it doesn't seem to work as expected."*  Okay, what does it do?  That should be all that is needed.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot, it doesn't make any difference even if I change the protocol to https. It still redirects to http.

Answer (score 0):

Update 1:

Well S3 changes took their own good time in reflecting with changes.
The protocol redirect to https seems to work now.

It took more than a day's time to reflect the changes.

In my experience, it usually takes 8 hours for DNS related change to reflect. But this redirection took a bit more than usual.

Anyone looking for how to do it :
[This is all you need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsQak.png)